# How does escaping work in mingw's bash being called from windows?

Tags: bash, cmd, mingw, msys2

For the life of me I really can't figure out how to pass parameters to mingw's from cmd so it prints two word, there is something going on here and I can't figure out the replacement rules.
So when I open mingw interactively, we get standard bash rules, but as soon as I use `mingw -c` I get something inescrutable.

I've tried from cmd.exe:

- `mingw -c "printf ^"Hello World!^""`:
  The syntax of the command is incorrect.
- `mingw -c "printf "Hello World!^""`:
  The syntax of the command is incorrect.
- `mingw -c "printf "Hello World!""`:
  The syntax of the command is incorrect.
- `mingw -c "printf Hello World!"`:
  Hello
- `mingw -c "printf Hello\ World!"`: Hello World!

(Okay so I think it works without quotation marks BUT if I try..)

- `mingw -c "printf $@" bash Hello\ World!`: Hello\

What???

- `mingw -c "printf $@" bash "Hello\ World!"`: Hello\
- `mingw -c "printf $@" bash "^"Hello\ World!^""`: Hello
  How would you print a single "?

The real reason why I ask this is because I want to run a command like this
`ln -s "$(which jupyter)" "/exports/jupyter"` from cmd by calling mingw -c

Answer (score 1):

I settled for

`` mingw -c "`"printf `"printf\\\\x20\\\\x22Hello\\\\x20World\\\\x21\\\\x22`"|bash -`"" ``

In Powershell, I don't know what is going on there, very weird shell expansion going on. Hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: Yes, I was going to say, be prepared to have 4-5 escapes to get it right. It's worth the time experimenting with toy problems to understand how these work. Start with `echo "Hello World'"` and keeping wrapping it with more "parent" calls from different systems. i.e. `echo -> powershell -> mingw -> bash -> someUtils -> ??? (-;! Good luck.

Comment: The reason is that I wanted to create shortcuts for programs installed on mingw with pacman such that they're available on windows.